# Running fan using java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I need to simulate a running fan with 3 buttons(start, reverse,stop) and a scroll bar to control the speed.
I wrote a code but and their are no errors but its not working.
At first the class extended Jframe and the window that has the buttons and the arcs of the fan appeared but when it extended Japplet it didn't appear.
But it didn't work both ways.

```
package Ass3_10203038;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import  java.awt.Adjustable;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Ass3_10203038 extends JApplet implements Runnable {
private static
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
Graphics fan;
JButton start = new JButton("Start");
JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
JButton reverse = new JButton("Reverse");
JScrollBar speed = new JScrollBar();
Thread timer = new Thread();
int thr=50;
int strtpt=0;
 JFrame frame= new JFrame();

@Override
public void run() {
    repaint();
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(thr);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

  }

   public Ass3_10203038() {
    final ArcsPanel arcs = new ArcsPanel();

    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    p.setSize(500, 500);
    p.add(arcs);
  //  p.setSize(5000, 5000);
    p.add(start);
    p.add(stop);
    p.add(reverse);
    p.add(speed);
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout());

   frame.add(p);
  add(frame);

   frame.setTitle("Fan");
    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  timer.start();

  for(int x=strtpt;x<362;x++)
 {if(x==361)
 x=0;
 else         
  arcs.initializex(x);
  arcs.paintComponent(fan);
 strtpt=x;
  }   


 }
 });

        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

  lock.lock();

   timer.start();

}
});

         reverse.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   timer.start();
    for(int x=strtpt;x>-1;x--)
    {if(x==0)
    x=360;

  else
    arcs.initializex(x);
      arcs.paintComponent(fan);
    strtpt=x;

     }


         }});

            speed.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener(){
                    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent ae){
                        try {
                            switch (thr){
                                    case AdjustmentEvent.UNIT_INCREMENT:
                                   Thread.sleep( thr+=2);
                                break;

                                    case AdjustmentEvent.UNIT_DECREMENT:
                                      Thread.sleep(thr-=2);
                                        break;
                                            }
                            int value = ae.getValue();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Ass3_10203038.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }

            });

    }
   /**
   * Main method
   */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ass3_10203038  window = new Ass3_10203038();

    window.setSize(500, 500);

    window.setLocation(50, 50); // Center the frame
     // frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);

   }
  }

 // The class for drawing arcs on a panel
  class ArcsPanel extends JPanel {
   // Draw four blades of a fan

   public int initializex(int x){

  return x;
   }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
    int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
    int radius = (int) (Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);


    int x = xCenter - radius;
    int y = yCenter - radius;

    {
        g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0+initializex(x), 30);
        g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90+initializex(x), 30);
        g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180+initializex(x), 30);
        g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270+initializex(x), 30);

    }

  }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems with this code, and I won't try to address all of them. However, I'll list the ones I notice and describe what is going wrong.

First off, your code crashes with an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
```

This happens in the `Ass3_10203038` constructor, where you try to add a `JFrame` to the new `Ass3_10203038` instance (which is a `JApplet`, and thereby a container). Since the `JFrame` only holds a `JPanel`, you can get around this by directly adding the `JPanel` to the `Ass3_10203038` instance. This will at least display your UI when running as Applet.

Next, clicking a button will generate a `NullPointerException`. This happens because you call `paintComponent` directly, passing in `fan` as the `Graphics` parameter - but you never initialize `fan` to anything in your code, so it is always null. As a solution, you should not call `paintComponent` directly, because you don't *have* a `Graphics` object that can be used to draw on the screen. The Swing system has this object, though, so we can ask it to repaint instead of calling `paintComponent` directly:

```
arcs.repaint();
```

Now the program goes into an infinite loop on the press of a button though. What happens is that this loop never ends:

```
for (int x = strtpt; x < 362; x++)
{
    if (x == 361)
        x = 0;
    else
        arcs.initializex(x);
    arcs.repaint();
    strtpt = x;
}
```

It always keeps looping because x never reaches 362. Given that you want the fan to spin continuously that makes a kind of sense, but since you are running this loop on the UI thread, it will freeze up the entire window. Apart from that, the fan would rotate *really* quickly, since there is no timing in this loop - it would go as fast as the computer can make it go, which is pretty fast indeed.

Apparently you tried to solve this problem by involving a `Thread` called `timer`:

```
timer.start();
```

However, since `timer` is just a blank `Thread` object this line does absolutely nothing (at least, nothing of any importance to your program). In order to run code in a thread, you have to either extend `Thread` and override the `run` method, or pass a `Runnable` to the constructor of `Thread`. However, I don't think raw `Thread`s will get us anywhere here, since they still don't really solve the timing problem. I suggest you look into `javax.swing.Timer`.

Even with this out of the way though, your fan blades still don't move. This is because your `paintComponent` method never actually sees any angle as input. It looks like you try to pass in an angle by calling `initializex(x)` in the loop shown above and in the `paintComponent` method, but `initializex` does not do anything except return its parameter - whatever you pass in, you get back out immediately. So in the `paintComponent` method, `initializex(x)` simply returns the value of x. This means that instead of you code:

```
g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0 + initializex(x), 30);
```

You could just as well have written

```
g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0 + x, 30);
```

with exactly the same effect.

I hope this explains a few of the things that went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code, but thank you so much 
i Just needed to organize the logic in my head

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package assign3_10203038;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;

public class Assign3_10203038 extends JFrame {

private JButton start = new JButton("Start");
private JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
private JButton reverse = new JButton("Reverse");
private JScrollBar speed = new JScrollBar();
private Thread timer;
private final ArcsPanel arcs;

 public Assign3_10203038() {
    arcs = new ArcsPanel();

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setSize(5000, 5000);
    p.add(arcs);
    p.add(start);
    p.add(stop);
    p.add(reverse);
    p.add(speed);
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    add(p);

    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            timer = new Thread(arcs);
            timer.start();


        }
    });

    speed.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent ae) {
            System.out.println(ae.getValue());
            arcs.speed(ae.getValue());
        }
    });


    reverse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            arcs.reverse();

        }
    });

    stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Assign3_10203038 window = new Assign3_10203038();

    //  (new Thread(window)).start();
    window.setSize(500, 500);

    window.setLocation(50, 50); // Center the frame
    //  window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
}

class ArcsPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
// Draw four blades of a fan

int thr = 1000;
int i = -20;

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        starting_x = (starting_x + i) % 360;
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(thr);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Assign3_10203038.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public void reverse() {
    i = -i;
}

 public void speed(int p) {
    thr = 1000 - (p += p) * 5;

 }
 int starting_x;

 public void initializex(int x_val) {
    starting_x = x_val;
 }

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
    int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
    int radius = (int) (Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);


 int x = xCenter - radius;
int y = yCenter - radius;

{
g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0 + starting_x, 30);
g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90 + starting_x, 30);
g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180 + starting_x, 30);
g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270 + starting_x, 30);

}

}
}
```